# Com SSIS Err on Schdeule ON 64 Bit Server

Tags: ssis

I am **using this in Script Component In SSIS**-->

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
           objXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
           objXL.Visible = false;
           Workbook objWorkbook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileNameWithFolderName, false, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
           Worksheet objSheet;

```
        //Get SheetName of the Workbook which contains exact the same columns
        for (int i = 1; i <=  objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count && strMatchedorNot==false; i++)
        {
```

& so on

**when i execute this directly, it runs without problem, but when i try to schedule this it shows this errr**

escription: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file '\10.177.189.12\C$\inetpub\WWW_TEST\Abc\Mapping Rules Upload\1000000023_elizafox_Jan-05-2010_113731.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:    ? The file name or path does not exist.  ? The file is being used by another program.  ? The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.     at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)     at ST_a8f4e90e3d884d578f79a2269c50080c.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)     at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  End Error  Warning: 2010-01-07 08:47:22.58     Code: 0x80019002     Source: LOOP Through Each Input File(Request Not Completed)      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  Warning: 2010-01-07 08:47:22.58     Code: 0x80019002     Source: SABRE_SVR      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  DTExec: The package execution returned

when i disable this step and schdeules this,Pkg run successfully.
i am running it thru 64-bit server.

Please help me.

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is an security issue since you try to access the admin share c$.

Did you already try to schedule under a different account?

Comment: Thanx Filburt. but the account i am using have Admin rights on c$.
but when i use Microsoft.ACE.4.0. to connect to Excel file. it runs successfully in Agent Job. I suspect that there's problem in Automation. i have added reference to Interop assembly.

please help me.

Comment: Maybe here is a hint: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/20aafd3d-0219-4706-abb4-e4b35aebb18e/